# Bug animation in translate with percentage on Safari/iOS adding via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, css, animation, safari

I think I found a bug related with percentages on Safari in the animations. I would like to know if really it is a bug or a Safari custom.

**Explanation of the bug:**

On Safari or iOS when you start an animation with a translate with percentages, the position is wrong and the animation is shown in another place.

**In the next example**, the square should not move because the transform is the same and it should start with a 10% 10% "margin" of its size. The bug occurs when it is adding via JavaScript after some time (like 500 ms).

**If you see the bug, you will see a jump from 0 0 to 10% 10% in Safari and iOS.**

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');


setTimeout( function(){
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}, 500);
```

```css
  div {
    background: red;
    
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

    -webkit-transform:  translate(10%, 10%);
    -webkit-animation: 1s bugAnimation;
  }


@-webkit-keyframes bugAnimation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate(10%, 10%);
    background: blue; /* To see the animation */
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate(10%, 10%);
    background: red; /* To see the animation */
  }
}
```

**Possible solutions:**

- Changing the percentage values by viewport units or another.

Obviously that options is not valid for all cases because I need the percentage but it could be a small solution for now if I know the size of the div (vw, vh, px...).

Do somebody know this bug?

Tested on Safari 10.1.1 and iOS 9.3.1 (with webview).

**EDIT:**
Really I need the translate2D because I am rotating a DIV in the center of the page and the size is unknown, an example:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');


setTimeout( function(){
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}, 500);
```

```css
  div {
    background: red;
    
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-animation: 1s bugAnimation;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
  }


@-webkit-keyframes bugAnimation {
 from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Why do you have transform in the div itself AND in the animation? As far as i can see that's what's causing the bug

Comment: @VilleKoo because my div is centering on the page. I need transform to do that. And in the animation I need rotate the div. I know the bug is with the two transforms because Safari/iOS is calculating wrong the position (it takes a position and after use another position to do the animation).

Comment: Does there any document could refer to this bug? I just read [the document from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/Functions.html) and seems it did support percentage in `translate()`. Not sure what goes wrong but the bug still existing both on macOS and iOS Safari right now.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, a workaround maybe using em instead of %

```js
    var div = document.createElement('div');


    setTimeout( function(){
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }, 500);
```

```css
  div {
    background: red;
    
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

    -webkit-animation: 1s bugAnimation forwards;
  }


@-webkit-keyframes bugAnimation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    background: blue; /* To see the animation */
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1.3em, 1.3em);
    background: red; /* To see the animation */
  }
}
```

Ok, please take another look at that approach. I wondered why you are using keyframed animation. Maybe the example is not representative but in this case you can just animate with a simple transition. Please take another look here:

```js
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("div").classList.add("animated");
    }, 1000);
```

```css
    div {
        background: red;

        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;

        -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
        -moz-transition: transform 1s;
        -ms-transition: transform 1s;
        -o-transition: transform 1s;
        transition: transform 1s;
    }

    .animated {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
    }
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: But I need the percentage because I am rotating a DIV on the center of the page and I don't know the real size. See my edit.

Comment: Does it not help? I am asking because em is also a relative measure. It is just not based on the parent's dimensions

Comment: I know, em is relative to the font-size. But the translate2D percentage is relative to its size. So if my DIV is 50% width of the page then I will need translate -50% of its size because I don't know the real size of the div. Your solution it would be usefully if my DIV had a 'em' size or some size relative to the font. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Thank you for your editing but like you said my example is not representative, it only is a simplified. In the real case I use different options in each frame to make the animation.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a Mac Safari issue,

I removed `-webkit-transform` property from `keyframes` which fixes the jumping problem on Safari and also works fine on Chrome too. Try this code,

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');


setTimeout( function(){
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}, 500);
```

```css
div {
    background: red;
    
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transform:  translate(10%, 10%);
    -webkit-animation: 1s bugAnimation;
  }


@-webkit-keyframes bugAnimation {
  from {
    background: blue; /* To see the animation */
  }
  to {
    background: red; /* To see the animation */
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course if you remove the transform then the bug is not shown. The problem is I need the transform because I use a rotation and translate. I am going to put an example in my question.